# Вложенные jlbyfhyst кавычки для JS, когда нельзя использовать обычные кавычки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть кусок кода который потом PhP засунет в массив для JS, это напрочь исключает мне возможность использовать обычные кавычки, так так JS воспримет их как синтаксис массива (ну или так же можно сказать об одинарных, если я буду использовать их как кавычки в синтаксисе массива, так что пусть исключенными будут обычные а не одинарные).

```
$aaa = "<div onclick='myfunction('".$bbb."');'>";
```

В куске кода выше видно, что имеет место быть неправильная расстановка одинарных кавычек, но как мне их сделать верными? Очень не хочется заменять их на какие то спец символы которые потом на JS заменять на кавычки на выходе. Наверняка есть какой то способ экранирования который подойдет для этого случая на стадии PhP, и что бы JS его воспринял верно.

Я конечно знаю про экранирование, но оно мне тут ничего не даст как я понимаю, так как HTML интерпритирует первые 2 кавычки независимо от того что одна будет ' а вторая \' как одну пару. Проблема еще в том, что я передаю URL, там наклонные палки.

Comment: так экранировать надо не `'`, а `"`, т.е. делать так: `$aaa = "<div onclick='myfunction(\"".$bbb."\");'>";`

Comment: Тогда PHP все съест ОК, но JS уйдет в аут думая, что это конец одного из значений массива. Я уже нашел решение сам только что.

Comment: так если `$bbb` уже массив, то зачем кавычки нужны? вы хотите массив как строку передать? т.е. что мешает передать `$aaa = "<div onclick='myfunction(".$bbb.");'>";`? вы бы значение `$bbb` в вопросе показали

Comment: и если уж надо экранировать, то экранировать сам текст, а не кавычки вокруг него (кавычки в тексте, например, можно экранировать через [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php))

Comment: Нет, по коду это не ясно, но массив $aaa а в нем готовые блоки HTML кода с одинарными кавычками. Я уже решил проблему. Сам додумался. Вспомнил, про тройное экранирование, оно и помогло:

$aaa = "<div onclick='myfunction(\\\"".$bbb."\\\");'>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам додумался. Вспомнил, про тройное экранирование, оно и помогло:

```
$aaa = "<div onclick='myfunction(\\\"".$bbb."\\\");'>";
```